# how to support bangla font in fpdf?

Tags: php, unicode, fonts, fpdf

I made the font in 'bangla.ttf' to 'cp1252' using terminal.

However, I don't know why it's not showing. is that correct or do you have any other solutions? Suggest me.

And I also took the converted file to the fpdf font file. so that I can access. I converted other language but this one is not working. I found a solution using tfpdf for unicode support But I can't show the bangla font in there. How to solve it?

[image]

Comment: rookie mistake. UTF-8 all the things.

Comment: how to do it. when generating the pdf?

Comment: why use cp1252? don't use that crap ever. start everything in utf-8 and your development will be a lot smoother

Comment: in fpdf they don't have utf-8 in their suggestion field.

Comment: they are giving me error. 

> Error: Encoding not found: utf-8

Comment: wow. unbelievable. try this https://github.com/DocnetUK/tfpdf

Comment: i like wkhtmltopdf, if you can make it in html, this can make the html a pdf https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2014/11/24/html-to-pdf-using-wkhtmltopdf/

Comment: How do I do that in php file. I need to download this pdf automatically. But this is a plugin. Through this can I download automatically?

Comment: you add the url. did you read my article?

Comment: your article is looooooooooooooooading.

Comment: Please use correct case shift - all commentators, too.

Comment: I didn't get you article @delboy1978uk. I think I need to use MPDF. But I want to use FPDF. How can I do that?

Comment: I've never used either. But I would never want to use a library that did not support UTF-8. What didn't you understand? Install wkhtmltopdf using apt-get or yum, then download the class file, and call it

Comment: Thanks bro. I'll try.